# Pip installation flandmark gets stuck on egg_info

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, egg

I am trying to install bob.ip.flandmark with the command

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.ip.flandmark#egg=bob.ip.flandmark"
```

The result is that I get a bunch of results that say that my requirements are already satisfied. If I then run the same command with `--upgrade`, I get the following output:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-aNZGa1/bob.ip.flandmark/

I have successfully installed and I can import both bob and xbob. The most common answer is to run

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

but this only tells me that my setuptools is already up-to-date.

My question is: How do I get it to work?
Also, if somebody can recommend me another face detection method, I'd love to hear it. I don't want to use haar cascades, as they make too make mistakes for me.

Comment: Could you paste the whole trace after you enter your pip command ?

Comment: I can post some output (it is too long):
pip install "git+https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.ip.flandmark#egg=bob.ip.flandmark" --upgrade
Collecting bob.ip.flandmark from git+https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.ip.flandmark#egg=bob.ip.flandmark
  Cloning https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.ip.flandmark to /tmp/pip-build-Uv2qkA/bob.ip.flandmark
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-build-Uv2qkA/bob.ip.flandmark/setup.py", line 52, in <module>
        boost_modules = boost_modules,

Comment: Part 2:
     File "/home/cedric/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: libboost_system.so.1.60.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Uv2qkA/bob.ip.flandmark/
You are using pip version 8.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: It seems that the real error is the `OSError: libboost_system.so.1.60.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` part.

Comment: Try and install `libboost-all-dev`